# Change icon class on checkbox select

Tags: jquery

From the code snippet below, I'd like to change the icon class when the checkbox gets checked using jQuery.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-1">Checkbox code here</div>
  <div class="item-2">Icons here (using Img tag)</div>
</div>
```

Note: The outer div with the container class is a repeating div.

Comment: I can't see a  code snippet anywhere.

Comment: What icon class and what checkbox? At least add the required html in (rather than placeholder text) so it matches your question

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change your class name on checkbox checked. See below example.

Here is your **HTML** like this.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item-1"><input type="Checkbox" name="1" class="check">1</div>
    <div class="other-class item-2">Icons here (using Img tag)</div> <!-- You need to keep class name `other-class` for change the class name -->
</div>
```

Here is the **jQuery** code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $( '.check' ).on('click', function(){

        if( $(this).is(":checked") ) {

            $('.container .other-class').removeClass('item-2').addClass('your-class-name');

        } else {

          $('.container .other-class').removeClass('your-class-name').addClass('item-2');

        }
  });
});
```